# Automating Postgresql database backup from small SSD to multiple harddrives daily

Tags: database, postgresql, backup, redundancy

Relative newcomer to sql and pg here so this is a relatively open question regarding backing up daily data from a stream. Specific commands / scripts would be appreciated if it's simple, otherwise I'm happy to be directed to more specific articles/tutorials on how to implement what needs to be done.

**Situation**

I'm logging various data streams from some external servers on the amount of a few GB/day every day. I want to be able to store this data onto larger harddrives which will then be used to pull information from for analysis at a later date.

**Hardware**

x1 SSD (128GB) (OS + application)

x2 HDD (4TB each) (storage, 2nd drive for redundancy)

**What needs to be done**

The current plan is to have the SSD store a temporary database consisting of the daily logged data. When server load is low (early morning), dump the entire temporary database onto two separate backup instances on each of the two storage disks. The motivation for storing a temp db is to reduce the load on the harddrives. Furthermore, the daily data is small enough that it will be able to copy over to the storage drives before server load picks up.

**Questions**

1. Is this an acceptable method?
2. Is it better/safer to just push data directly to one of the storage drives, consider that the primary database, and automate a scheduled backup from that drive to the 2nd storage drive?
3. What specific commands would be required to do this to ensure data integrity (i.e. while a backup is in progress, new data will still be being logged)

At a later date when budget allows the hardware will be upgraded but the above is what's in place for now.

thanks!

Comment: Are you familiar with PITR / WAL archiving?

Comment: @CraigRinger I am not; however I am currently reading the pg docs about it now

Answer (score 0):

First rule when building a backup system - do the simplest thing that works for you.

Running pg_dump will ensure data integrity. You *will* want to pay attention to what the last item backed up is to make sure you don't delete anything newer than that. After deleting the data you may well want to run a CLUSTER or VACUUM FULL on various tables if you can afford the logging.

Another option would be to have an empty template database and do something like:

1. Halt application + disconnect
2. Rename database from "current_db" to "old_db"
3. CREATE DATABASE current_db TEMPLATE my_template_db
4. Copy over any other bits you need (sequence numbers etc)
5. Reconnect the application
6. Dump old_db + copy backups to other disks.

If what you actually want is two separate live databases, one small quick one and one larger for long-running queries then investigate tablespaces. Create two tablespaces - the default on the big disks and the "small" one on your SSD. Put your small DB on the SSD. Then you can just copy from one table to another with foreign-data-wrappers (FDW) or dump/restore etc.

Comment: Hi @RichardHuxton, thanks for your reply. Ideally the database isn't disconnected as there is always the possibility for data to be arriving. There only needs to be a single live database, but that database needs to be continuously backed up at least once a day.   What's your opinion on holding a small temp database on the SSD and using that to dump to the storage harddrives, instead of continuously writing to the storage HDDs. Not worth the extra level of complication? The justification being copying from the SSD in chunks would reduce wear on the HDD.